# Read out result of a PageMethod into a jQuery-script

Tags: jquery, pagemethods, webmethod

I am quite a jQuery novice and try to read out the result of a PageMethod into
my jQuery script. I have a ScriptManager installed and the following WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string CheckSystemDefault(string _id)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(_id);
        addressTypeRepository = new AddressTypeRepository();

        AddressType addressType = addressTypeRepository.GetById(id);

        if (addressType.IsSystemDefault == true)
            return "IsSystemDefault";
        else
            return "IsNotSystemDefault";
    }
```

I use this to check if an object has the property IsSystemDefault.

In the script, I hand over the id from the url and want to evaluate the result:

```
var id = $(document).getUrlParam("id");
var check = PageMethods.CheckSystemDefault(id);
if (check == "IsSystemDefault") {
...
}
if (check == "IsNotSystemDefault") {
...
}
```

But as a result, the variable "check" is undefined. What do I have to change?

Comment: When you debug with a breakpoint in the web method, do you hit that break point, and does the web method complete without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in my jQuery-script was not correct.

It has to be the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var id = $(document).getUrlParam("id"); 

        PageMethods.CheckSystemDefault(id, function(result) {
            if (result == "IsSystemDefault")
                // do something
            else
                // do something
        });

    });    

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable page methods in the script manager. Have you specified EnablePageMethods="true" in the script manager element as the last attribute below shows?

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server"
    EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true"
    ID="ScriptManager1"
    EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```